# How do I use a variable property file name in Spring?

Tags: java, spring

I'm trying to separate an application's configuration files from its war.
I want to keep all properties files in a directory on the disk. Then, the only property required inside the war would be the path to the configuration directory (let's say that would be in a file named `config.properties`):

```
config.dir = /home/me/config
```

Now in the spring configuration, I want to load this file (so that I know where the others are), and then the external files:

```
<bean id="propertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer"
 class="org.springframework.context.support.PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer">
    <property name="locations">
        <list>
            <value>classpath:META-INF/config.properties</value>
            <value>${config.dir}/other.properties</value>
        </list>
    </property>
</bean>
```

But this doesn't work, the placeholder is not resolved:

```
java.io.FileNotFoundException: class path resource [${config.dir}/config.properties] cannot be opened because it does not exist
```

I also tried using a separate bean of type `PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer` - it didn't help much.

Do you know how I could accomplish this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This can be resolved by registering a [PropertySource](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.2.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/core/env/PropertySource.html) for the default environment. One of the ways this can be done is using Java Configuration:

```
@Configuration
@PropertySource("classpath:META-INF/config.properties")
public class MyConfig {

}
```

With this in place the placeholder should get resolved:

```
<bean id="propertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer"
 class="org.springframework.context.support.PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer">
    <property name="locations">
        <list>
            <value>${config.dir}/other.properties</value>
        </list>
    </property>
</bean>
```

Answer (score 3):

The problem is that the configurer bean has to be fully constructed before it can resolve placeholders in the other bean definitions in the context, so you can't use a placeholder expression in the definition of the configurer that would need to be resolved by the configurer itself.

You could instead put the path to your config dir into `web.xml` as a `context-param`

```xml
<context-param>
  <param-name>configDir</param-name>
  <param-value>/home/me/config</param-value>
</context-param>
```

and then access it as `#{contextParameters.configDir}` in your Spring config

```xml
<bean id="propertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer"
 class="org.springframework.context.support.PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer">
    <property name="locations">
        <list>
            <value>#{contextParameters.configDir}/other.properties</value>
        </list>
    </property>
</bean>
```

Or you may be able to do it with two separate configurer beans with different values of `placeholderPrefix`, one loading the `config.properties` and then filling in the `@{config.dir}` placeholder in the other, which then loads the external config file.